# Catching CommandOnCooldown Error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot that has a cooldown and I am attempting to make an event that when the `CommandOnCooldown` Error occurs, the bot will DM them how much longer they have to wait. Here is my code and it all looks okay, but it doesn't know what retry_after means:

```
@bot.event
async def on_CommandOnCooldown():
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, 'You are on cooldown. Try again in {:.2f}s'.format(retry_after))

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def getalt(ctx):
    msg = ["a list of stuff"]
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, random.choice(msg))
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Alt Has Been Seen To Your DMs")
    await bot.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=2)
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, "Please Wait 30 Seconds Before Using This Command Again. If you do not wait the full time then you won't be sent an alt.")
```

I am using references from https://git.radiobrony.fr/MKody/discord.py/commit/cd0de57d13b15f709aaacf78ce611dd87e0784ce

Comment: what is the error description?

Comment: I don’t believe `on_CommandOnCooldown` is an actual discord event. It’s said on the documentation that cooldown raises an exception to the local error handle, which will be the `on_command_error` event error handle. If you add a print statement infront of `bot.send_message` of `on_CommandOnCooldown` function, does it actually print anything?

Comment: @abccd this is the error raised... raise CommandOnCooldown(bucket, retry_after)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandOnCooldown: You are on cooldown. Try again in 25.84s

Comment: Yup, exactly, I will write an answer if no one answers soon (since I don’t have a PC with me to verify my answer). `CommandOnCooldown` isn’t an event in discord py, it’s a discord exception. What you’re doing isn’t how you catch an exception in discord

Comment: @abccd ok thank you because I'm new to all of this stuff and I'm just try to self teach myself as I go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the general format for catching exceptions when using discord.py:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('$')

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send('This command is on a %.2fs cooldown' % error.retry_after)
    raise error  # re-raise the error so all the errors will still show up in console
  

@commands.cooldown(1, 30)
@bot.command()
async def getalt(ctx):
    await ctx.send('in getalt')

bot.run('token')
```

The `getalt` is the command, which has a 30-second cooldown, is caught by the `on_command_error` event, in turns will send a message to the channel. If you have anything else that you’re unclear about, please refer to the detailed documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html).

Comment: @KaitlynWathen I might’ve forgotten something when I wrote the answer. But I now added in, preferably you should add an `raise error` in the error handle to re raise the error or else none of the errors will show up on your console, since the error handle catches every single error that was raised, and that it would be nice to see the exceptions.

Comment: N.B. as per the migration to discord.py v1.0, [`pass_context=True` has been deprecated](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html?highlight=pass_context#context-changes) and [the `context` (`ctx`) parameter comes before the `error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html?highlight=pass_context#id2).